# Is it possible to view the ControlFlow or Pending Tasks with protractor?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm having some long delays while protractor waits to execute the next statement in my tests.  I've had to update my config to increase the timeout period to 30 seconds as the default of 11 seconds was too short. As long as I have this long timeout, all of my tests run without a problem. However, I'd prefer if my tests didn't take minutes to finish.

I'm guessing this is due to some task/http call or a timeout that is forcing protractor to wait this long, however, I have tracked down all of the timeouts in my code base and either removed them or put them inside of an `ngZone.runOutsideOfAngular` call.  I'm guessing it may be one of the node modules I have included in my project, but I'm having trouble tracking it down.

Is there a way to view the pending tasks or control flow with protractor so I can see where it's getting hung up?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the synchronisation?

Comment: @demouser123 I have, but, this makes writing tests a bit more verbose with all of the waits you have to place in the code, so I was hoping to avoid doing that and let protractor do the work for me...